# Proper way ( jshint.com validated ) to use 'this' | Assignment to a var

Tags: javascript

Why does assigning a this to a var break jshint.com

I know how to bypass it in jshint.com.

Also, I know how to get rid of it.

But I want to know what definition of strict this breaks.

**Example Code**

```
function vFlipBP( element_or_string ) {
    var previous_page_element,
        previous_tag_element,
        current_page_element,
        select_element;
    if( typeof ( element_or_string ) === 'string' ) {
        select_element = document.getElementById( element_or_string );
    } else {
        select_element = this; // Possible strict violation <- error here
    }
.
.
.
```

**Call Type 1**

```
document.getElementById( this.tag_array[element] ).onclick = vFlipBP;
```

**Call Type 2**

```
vFlipBP( this.tag_array[0] ); // string parameter
```

Comment: In what context are you invoking `vFlipBP`? Do you use `.call()/.apply()` or `new`? Or are you doing regular function invocations?

Comment: The term *"strict violation"* is very misleading. It isn't violating anything. It's just that if you're in strict mode, the value of `this` could be different than if you're not. This depends on how the function is invoked.

Comment: I use it (1) as a call back to eventListeners with no parameters and (2) a direct call with a string parameter

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: So the direct call might be the issue, because `this` will be `undefined` in strict mode, and the global object when not in strict mode. Ignore it anyway.

Comment: Added in call types to question.

Comment: So in your **Call Type 2**, `this` will be the global object, unless you're in *strict mode*, in which case it will be `undefined`. So what it ultimately means is that the value of `this` may not be what you expect. But you've got that scenario covered, as long as you always pass a *string* argument for that call type.

Comment: @am_not...thanks...I need to update my code so it makes sense too...pretty sure element_or_string...should be element_or_undefined.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Since it's being used as an event handler, it'll be `string_or_event_object_or_undefined`. In standards compliant browsers, the first argument to a handler is the `event` object, but `undefined` in non-compliant browsers, like IE8 and lower. ...though if you've no use for the `event` object, you might as well consider it `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks when `this` isn't bound to a value, which might appear to be the case to JSHint because it's a function declaration you're in, not a function literal. If you'll always be giving `this` a value (using `call` or `apply`, or by assigning the function to a property) then you can safely ignore it.

Comment: How does it being a function declaration (instead of a function expression) make a difference?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: You generally expect function declarations to be called directly, whereas function literals are usually assigned to properties. I think it's a little silly, though, because either could be used in the opposite manner. (Or it could be a constructor - but constructors should start with a capital letter.)

Comment: so it has something to do with what this is bound to?

Comment: @minitech Yes, the point is that the invocation options of a function don't depend on how it was created. Btw, I avoid function declarations - they are redundant and add a layer of confusion and complexity to the language that is not needed. `var f = function ...` gets the job done just fine.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I would say exactly the opposite in regards to function declarations. I find them much easier to read than the equivalent `var name = function() {`, especially for constructors. Use function literals when you want a function literal and function declarations when you want to declare a function - simple as that.

Comment: @minitech I'm a minimalist. I don't think that the language needs two similar notations for defining functions. "Killing" one of them makes the language simpler and less confusing. Simple as that `:P` (Btw, I'm pretty sure the reader-friendliness is pretty much the same for both notations.)